# JasperReport en war de maven

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, war

Buen día comunidad.
EL problema es el siguiente estoy trabajando con un proyecto en **Maven** y **JasperReport**, el problema es el siguiente no logro localizar el path al archivo **.jasper** para que este pueda llenar el reporte en cuestión.

Ya he logrado aumentar el archivo **.jasper** dentro del war como se los muestro a continuación:

[image: jasper en war]

sin embargo no sé como aplicar la ruta al archivo para que este sea llenado, he intentado con lo siguiente:

```java
private final static String reporteIva = "ReporteIva.jasper"; 

    public JasperPrint reportIva(Connection con, HashMap<String, Object> data) {

        try {

            JasperReport js = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource(reporteIva));
            JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(js, data, con);
            return report;
            //return null;

        } catch (JRException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Sin embargo el reporte no es generado. Y tengo la excepción que el reporte no fue encontrado(el archivo **.jasper**). Todo esto solo cuando genero el **war** sin embargo en pruebas el proyecto marcha bien.

Comment: Si utilizas maven mete el fichero jasper en la carpeta resources. O en la carpeta de fuentes para que te lo copie en WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, en un servlet tengo una imagen en `WebContent/image/cherry.png`
y tengo el archivo de `WebContent/reportes/ReporteCursoJasper.jrxml`
Entonces uso este código y funciona

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();       
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conexion=null;
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mibd","user","pass");

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/reportes/ReporteCursoJasper.jrxml"));
            HashMap<String, Object> parameters= new HashMap<String, Object>();
            parameters.put("cherry.jpg",request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/image/cherry.jpg"));

            bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport,parameters,conexion);          
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            servletOutputStream.flush();
            servletOutputStream.close();
        }catch(JRException|ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e){

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());
        }
    }
```

Pero tienes que guardar tu proyecto como `.jrxml` y no como `.jasper`

Comment: voy a intentarlo y te aviso como va. Gracias

Comment: no funcionó, no puedo acceder a la ruta del archivo pues al darle **mvn clean package** solo obtengo los **.class** y el resto de archivos son borrados

Comment: Si sabes que hace clean, verdad?? Borra el directorio de salida o en este caso package. Creo que tu mismo estas borrando lo que compilas. Mira este [tutorial de maven](https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-war-file-from-eclipse-using-maven-plugin-apache-maven-war-plugin-usage/) y un [tutorial en español de maven](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2006/09/19/maven/) Ninguno dice que hagas clean package. Si estas en eclipse solo tienes que generar el war como normalmente se hace, al tener un pom.xml las dependencias se importan automáticamente.

Comment: ya logré que aunque use **mvn clean package** no borre al reporte y este sea agregado dentro de **WEB-INF/classes** sin embargo no logro acceder a el.